# Add days in a date with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need add days in dates inside an array, like the image below:
[image: data.getDate()]

When select show Semanal (weekly), add 7 days on each date, but my code is adding the same day on all subsequent dates:

```js
var number_installments = 10, frequency = 1;
for(let i = 1; i <= number_installments; i++){
    // console.log('Frequencia: ' + frequency)
    let data = new Date();
    let dia = data.getDate(), mes = data.getMonth(), ano = data.getFullYear(), zero = '';
    if((mes + i) <= 9){
        zero = '0';
    }
    let due_date = dia + '/' + zero + (mes + i) + '/' + ano;;
    //console.log(i)
    if(frequency == 1 && i != 1){
        dia = data.getDate() + 7;
        due_date = dia + '/' + zero + (mes + 1) + '/' + ano;
        
    }
    console.log(due_date);
}
```

Comment: So where do you set the html?

Comment: sorry man, I didn't understand your question

Comment: Where do you put the date back into the table. I do not see the code that does that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have initialised your "data" object in every iteration which will only give the current date and day. Which after adding 7 results the same.

May be that comes from data externally.

```
let data = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting date like that you can use,

`var today = date.toJSON().slice(0,10)`

which would result in the full date. It would make your code simpler to read and change.

Comment: But this is not my problem, I need to add days in dates arrays

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve with the help of Abhay H Soningra

```js
var number_installments = 10, frequency = 1;
let data = new Date();
let dia = data.getDate(), mes = data.getMonth(), ano = data.getFullYear(), zero = '0', max_days, max_months = 12;
if(dia % 2 == 0){
    max_days = 31;
} else{
    max_days = 30;
}
for(let i = 1; i <= number_installments; i++){
    // console.log('Frequencia: ' + frequency)    
    if((mes + i) <= 9){
        zero = '0';
    }
    let due_date = dia + '/' + zero + (mes + i) + '/' + ano;;
    //console.log(i)
  if(frequency == 1 && i != 1){
      dia = dia + 7;
      if(dia > max_days){
          mes  = mes + 1;
          dia = data.getDate();
      }
      if((mes + 1) > max_months){
          mes = data.getMonth();
          ano = ano + 1;
      }
      due_date = dia + '/' + zero + (mes + 1) + '/' + ano;
  }
    console.log(due_date);
}
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Cheers